# Is there a JQL query that checks if a specific person has updated anything in the Jira ticket from the past week?

Tags: jira, jql

I can figure out how to see who it was last updated by, but I'm looking for a list of Jira Tickets that has been updated by someone at any point during the week. Even if someone else updated it afterwards.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if you're referring to Jira Server/DC or Jira Cloud. For on-premise solutions, here is my answer.

**Jira 7.x and lower**

There are no JQL functions to get this information. With out-of-the-box functions, you can actually get information only about status changes by a certain user or query history of certain system fields - see Aaron's answer.

```
status changed by currentUser() AFTER startOfWeek()
assignee was currentUser() AFTER startOfWeek()
assignee was currentUser() AFTER startOfWeek() AND updated > startOfWeek()
```

With [ScriptRunner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/6820/scriptrunner-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview) installed, you will have more JQL functions available and you can get more information about worklogs and comments:

```
issueFunction in commentedBy("username after startOfWeek()")
issueFunction in workLogged("by username after startOfWeek()")
```

Similarly with [JQL Tricks](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/31399/jql-tricks-plugin?hosting=server&tab=overview) add-on ([documentation](https://www.j-tricks.com/jql-tricks-plugin.html)).

**Jira 8+**

Atlassian has added (limited) support after 15 years (!) of requesting this feature ([JRASERVER-1973](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-1973)). There is the new JQL function `updatedBy`.

```
issue in updatedBy(username)
issue in updatedBy(username, -7w)
```

Unfortunately, this JQL function is unable to work with relative functions (`currentUser()`, `startOfWeek()`).

See more information about this JQL function in [Atlassian Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwareserver080/advanced-searching-functions-reference-967899663.html#Advancedsearching-functionsreference-approverupdatedBy()).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what changes you are looking for. Jira does have limited support for search functions on history enabled fields (specifically: `Assignee`, `Fix Version`, `Priority`, `Reporter`, `Resolution` and `Status`)

Meaning you could do a search similar to:

```
status changed by "replace_user_name_here" AFTER startOfWeek();
```

There would be ways to restrict workflows to automatically update one of those fields if you needed a wider net of changes caught by the history (i.e. have comments trigger changes of status as a part of a business logic), but that would be up to the configuration of your business's logic and how you intend to utilize the history field.